# execute shell command in python using subprocess.run()

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I have a function that runs the command to move all files from sub-folders to one folder.

```
def move_images_to_one_folder(scr, dst):
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
        print('Destination Created: ', dst)

    cmd = 'find ' + \
        os.path.join(scr) + ' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ' + \
        os.path.join(dst)

    execute_cmd = run([cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(execute_cmd.stdout.read())
```

I keep getting the error that the file doesn't exist.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'find /home/yury.stanev/Downloads/lfw-deepfunneled/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /home/yury.stanev/4nn3-project/clean_cnn_outputs/data/': 'find /home/yury.stanev/Downloads/lfw-deepfunneled/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /home/yury.stanev/4nn3-project/clean_cnn_outputs/data/'
```

I've manually created the destination folder and ran the command in `bash` shell the result were as expected, all the files were moved. I've added a condition in the function to check for `dst` folder and create it if doesn't exist, but it doesn't seems to run.

I suspect it might be the issue with path. What's the possible cause for this, and is there a fix?

Comment: try `run([cmd.split()], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Answer (score 0):

You `cmd`variable input is a single string. If you want to execute a command with `subprocess.run()`, you have to put all seperate parts which are seperated of eachother with a space into a list of strings, like this:

`execute_cmd = run(["find", os.path.join(scr), "-type", "f", "-print0", "|", "xargs", "-0", "mv", "-t", os.path.join(dst)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: Making progress, but it seems that the `find` command wants me to quote the path `find: paths must precede expression: `|'`. Shouldn't `str()` take care of that?